# String.replaceAll is considerably slower than doing the job yourself

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have an old piece of code that performs find and replace of tokens within a string.

It receives a map of `from` and `to` pairs, iterates over them and for each of those pairs, iterates over the target string, looks for the `from` using `indexOf()`, and replaces it with the value of `to`. It does all the work on a `StringBuffer` and eventually returns a `String`.

I replaced that code with this line: `replaceAll("[,. ]*", "");`
And I ran some comparative performance tests.
When comparing for `1,000,000` iterations, I got this:

> Old Code: 1287ms
>   New Code: 4605ms

3 times longer!

I then tried replacing it with 3 calls to `replace`:
 `replace(",", "");`
 `replace(".", "");`
 `replace(" ", "");`

This resulted with the following results:

> Old Code: 1295
>   New Code: 3524

2 times longer!

Any idea why `replace` and `replaceAll` are so inefficient? Can I do something to make it faster?

---

**Edit:** Thanks for all the answers - the main problem was indeed that `[,. ]*` did not do what I wanted it to do. Changing it to be `[,. ]+` almost equaled the performance of the non-Regex based solution.
Using a pre-compiled regex helped, but was marginal. (It is a solution very applicable for my problem.

Test code:
[Replace string with Regex: [,. ]*](http://ideone.com/66cVN)
[Replace string with Regex: [,. ]+](http://ideone.com/3Ed2A)
[Replace string with Regex: [,. ]+ and Pre-Compiled Pattern](http://ideone.com/tmDD1)

Comment: Oh the joy of regular expressions...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

While using regular expressions imparts **some** performance impact, it should not be as terrible.

Note that using [`String.replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will compile the regular expression **each time** you call it.

You can avoid that by explicitly using a [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) object:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,. ]+");

// repeat only the following part:
String output = p.matcher(input).replaceAll("");
```

Note also that using `+` instead of `*` avoids replacing empty strings and therefore might also speed up the process.

Comment: @Lukas: it doesn't change *what* is done (in this case, where the replacement is the empty string). It *might* change the performance characteristics, but I don't know if leaving out `+` is faster or slower.

Comment: @Joachim, interestingly, with a simple benchmark test on your solution, `[]+` seems the fastest (1x), `[]` in the middle (1.5x) , and `[]*` the slowest (2x).

Comment: This answer assumes that the map he receives is reused over and over again.

Comment: @Joachim, []* matches the empty String "". So, for each character, a match is found of "" and replaced by "". This causes it to be slower. You can test it by doing ....replaceAll("$$$$") and watching the output.

Comment: @SJuan76: I'm well aware of that (I already explained that in my answer). The only thing I didn't know was if `replaceAll("[,. ]+", "")` would be slower or faster than `replaceAll("[,. ]", "")`.

Comment: @Joachim "some"? why are we now afraid to call out serious performance issues? Is it because the Knuth quoting brigade will pop-up with a useless essay on premature optimisation blah blah. The performance of replaceAll is terrible. If it is in the inner loop of some text processing code it can be *the* major overhead.

Comment: @rghome: I don't know why you think this is about fear. That sentence (written in 2011, by the way) is about the fact that you can certainly solve this with regexes with better performance than what OP was describing. And it turns out if you write a better regex, then performance gets much better indeed.

Comment: @rghome: and as an off-topic comment: you complain about the "Knuth quoting brigade" and describe yourself as a "serial downvoter". This is not a war or a fight, we're all just trying to write better software.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Please don't take my comment too seriously. But Pattern.compile is really expensive if called repeatedly (I know, I am looking at a profiled system now), and I find there can be a tendency on SO to water-down performance issues. In the interests of better software, I don't think we need to continually qualify every performance answer. So I am just pushing back a bit against the climate.

Answer (score 10):

`replace` and `replaceAll` uses **regex** internally which in most cases gives a serious [performance impact](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/regex/Pattern.java.htm) compared to e.g., [`StringUtils.replace(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

[`String.replaceAll()`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/lang/java/lang/String.java.htm):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
        return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this ).replaceAll(
             replacement);
}
```

[`String.replace()`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/lang/java/lang/String.java.htm) uses Pattern.compile underneath.

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
  return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL)
         .matcher(this ).replaceAll(
           Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

Also see [Replace all occurrences of substring in a string - which is more efficient in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407592/replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-which-is-more-efficient-in-jav)

Comment: `replace()` doesn't use regex.

Comment: @Adeel, `String.replace(char, char)` doesn't. `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` does.

Comment: @Lukas: None of those does. BTW, `replace(char, char)` is out of question, because it can't use regex, whatsoever, and the OP never used it.

Comment: @Lukas `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` uses a compiled pattern, true, but not compiled against a regular expression.

Comment: @Sean, yes +1, although the expression `abc` is still technically a valid regular expression.

Comment: @Johan yep, it's also the first three words of a children's song. (Which is also irrelevant)

Comment: More over, and at least in Java 8, `Matcher#replaceAll` uses a `StringBuffer` for wroking.

Answer (score 4):

As I have put in a comment [,. ]* matches the empty String "". So, every "space" between characters matches the pattern. It is only noted in performance because you are replacing a lot of "" by "".

Try doing this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,. ]*");
System.out.println(p.matcher("Hello World").replaceAll("$$$");
```

It returns:

H$$$e$$$l$$$o$$$$$$W$$$o$$$r$$$l$$$d$$$!$$$

No wonder it is slower that doing it "by hand"! You should try with [,. ]+

Comment: Thanks - that explains why it worked so hard to perform the replacement

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to `replaceAll("[,. ]*", "")` it's not that big of a surprise since it relies on regular expressions. The regex engine creates an automaton which it runs over the input. Some overhead is expected.

The second approach (`replace(",", "")...`) also uses regular expressions internally. Here the given pattern is however compiled using `Pattern.LITERAL` so the regular expression overhead should be negligable.) In this case it is probably due to the fact that `Strings` are immutable (however small change you do, you will create a new string) and thus not as efficient as `StringBuffers` which manipulate the string in-place.

Comment: @aiiobe: `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` uses regular expressions internally...

Comment: Yes, but with `Pattern.LITERAL` which in effect turns off all regexp overhead.

Comment: But that precisely means it doesn't, you can only pass a regex to it, but it will not work as expected, I suppose.

Comment: Still, the compilation for a `LITERAL` pattern shouldn't be super complicated, eh? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but for the record, since **Java 9**, the performance characteristics of String.replace(String,String) has changed, it now does **not** use Pattern under the hood

https://medium.com/javarevisited/micro-optimizations-in-java-string-replaceall-c6d0edf2ef6