# What is the most convenient way to read from console in Java?

Tags: java, input, io

I like to read from a console in Java. What is the most convenient way to do it for the sake of the processing of the input? For example I want to read a single char or an integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: click the check mark by the answer that fixed your problem please

Comment: Yeah, it could point to the right thing, but if I don't know if Scanner or BufferedReader, or something else is better to ask what.

Comment: what do you mean with better?

Comment: I mean I have encountered the above mentioned ways, but I don't know what is more suitable in a specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int toBeRead = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: Be aware that `replace()` and `replaceAll()` are both slow because many many string objects are created inside the method call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262397/string-replaceall-is-considerably-slower-than-doing-the-job-yourself

Answer (score 0):

`import java.util.Scanner`

`Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);`
`sc.nextInt();`