# String replace in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have String as:

```
"change(String.valueOf(data.get("abc")),data.get("xyz"),data.get("def"))"
```

I want to change it to:

```
change(String.valueOf(data.get("abc")),String.valueOf(data.get("xyz")),String.valueOf(data.get("def")))".
```

How can I do the above operation using Java regex?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use : `toString().replace("a", "o);`

Example :

```
private String txt = "This is a text"

public static void main() String[arg] {

    String rplc = txt.replace("i", "o");
    System.out.print(rplc);

}
```

Output: Thos os a text

Answer (score 0):

```
yourString.replaceAll("String.valueOf(data.get(").replaceAll("zzzzz").replaceAll("data.get(", "String.valueOf(data.get(").replaceAll("zzzzz", "String.valueOf(data.get(")
```

with 3 replaces

it is easer than using regex

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, this simple replace should be enough:

```
result = source.replace(",data.get(\"");
```

For simple cases like this, you don't really need Regex (`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`) as [using the regular replace is much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262397/string-replaceall-is-considerably-slower-than-doing-the-job-yourself) (`String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`)