# Replace all occurrences of String in file (Java)

Tags: java, string, file, io, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace all occurrences of substring in a string - which is more efficient in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407592/replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-which-is-more-efficient-in-ja)

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of **\t** (tab) with **four spaces** in a file.
I've been searching for a while but couldn't find anything useful.

I found out that I need to create a temporary file.

Comment: Do you mean programatically or with a text editor?

Comment: programatically in Java. I should probably state that in the title..

Comment: @ant No, OP wants the whole shebang -- create temp file, open file, read, write, close, delete old, rename temp to real name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a function for this called [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
String output = input.replace("\t","    ");
```

to do this with a file create a [temp file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) and open a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) for it

open a [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html) for the original file

the in a loop call `readln()`, check for null, `replace("\t","    ")` and `write` on the appropriate objects

then close the reader and writer and [`delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) the original file and [`rename()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) the temp file to the original file

Comment: I guess You meant replaceAll("\t","    ");

Comment: @Shine no. `replaceAll` works with a regexp as an input, while `replace` uses a `CharSequence`. No need for regexps here.

Comment: @Guillaume yes, you're right, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method like

```
String str = "your string";
String a = "    "; // [4 spaces]
String result = str.replaceAll("\t", a);
```